# Populate a detail view with (correct) txt-file

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a tableview with country names. When a cell is tapped I want it to move to a detail view with text about the country. I have a separate txt-file for each country with the same name as the title in the cell (e.g. USA.txt).

How do I display these txt-files in the detail view?

My code so far looks like this:

TableViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
```

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_Title = @[@”Afganistan”,
        @”Albania”,
        @”Algeria”,

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

int row = [indexPath row];

cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];

return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];
    detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row]];
  }
}
```

DetailViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

_TitleLabel.text = _DetailModal[0];

self.navigationItem.title = _DetailModal[0];

}
```

I found the code below here on StackOverflow but I don’t know how to implement it.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@”Afganistan” ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need can take one more `UILabel`(say detailLabel) to display the content of `.txt` files.
In ViewDidLoad of `DetailViewController`, add below lines

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:_DetailModal[0] ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
self.detailLabel.text = content
self.detailLabel.numberOflines = 0
```